Why did Amir vomit in the sink when he felt guilty?
On page 28 Amir says that when he suddenly felt guilty, he bolted to the bathroom and vomited in the sink. Why did Amir vomit? Is that a ritual in Afghanistan that when one feels guilty they need to vomit, or something else?

Powerful emotions such as fear or, in this case, self-disgust make some people feel nauseous.
